# relative xpath from webelement to another webelement

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

so I am trying to get from one webelement to another webelement by using XPath.
So this is the path where the webelement is located, which I find by using "findElementsByClassName".

```
//*[@id="appView2"]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody[3]/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div
```

And this is where I need to get to.

```
//*[@id="appView2"]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody[3]/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[1]/span
```

I can't just point to it directly since the column and row change for each web element.

I have tried a couple of different paths like:

```
.//.//.//.//div[1]/span
```

But it can't find the element.

If someone got a better solution, that would also work.

Thanks!

Comment: please add html source so that we can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't rely on indexes like this (eg div[3] or tbody[3]). It makes your implementation brittle which will break with the slightest change to the html. Instead of

`//*[@id="appView2"]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody[3]/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div`

You could do something like

`//*[@id="appView2"]//table[@class='xxx']//div[text()='xxx']`

In answer to your original question, instead of

`.//.//.//.//div[1]/span`

It will be something like

`../../../../div[1]/span`

Comment: The solution did work, so thanks!

Also while searching around I found out, I could just use "findElementsByClassName" to find the first element, like this:
unitDriver.findElementsByClassName("calendar-time-info");

Comment: Yes, use class names, ids or text in the html rather than using very specific xpath with indexes. This way the html can change over time without breaking your xpaths. If you have control over the html, the best thing you can do is put IDs on everything you need to reference and avoid xpaths all together